# How can I scale the fixed size html content to fit the UIwebview frame size?(the content size is much smaller than the frame size)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am now doing a advertSDK project like inmobi, the user is allowed to create the banner frame and  locate them by CGrectmake, so I will create a UIWebview as they required, then in the UIwebview I  just to load the html content to show it in the right position.

The question is: the banner content has a fixed size : 360 * 100, however in iphone 6s simulator, it is too small, I tried to set

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES
```

but it has no effects.

Anyone has a good idea to solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the UIWebView delegate methods and resize the web view like I'm doing here:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, however, I do not want to change the size of the UIWebview, I prefer to keep the size of the UIWebview unchanged and scale the content to a proper size

Comment: The content most of the times is scaled automatically